# How can 3 different Apple Music users share the same Apple TV? (family or not family plan)

Tags: apple-id, appletv, apple-music

I have a 4th generation Apple TV, and listen to Apple Music on my watch (with bluetooth) and my iPhone.

I want to prevent anyone who uses the Apple TV from playing or saving music that changes my "For You" playlist on the TV. (this seems to be a curated list of songs that is based on my past listening history).

How can I separate users on a shared Apple TV?  ... or is Apple TV supposed to be used for a single person?

Comment: Have you tried ensuring that users sign in to _their_ own individual Apple IDs when using the ATV4?

Answer (score 1):

You can [set up multiple Apple ID's](http://amp.imore.com/how-set-multiple-accounts-your-apple-tv) on the Apple TV and have each user switch every time they use it.

You may opt to create a separate/new account that you leave signed in, so that somebody doesn't accidentally use yours (requiring you to sign in and out of your account every time).

> **How to add multiple accounts to Apple TV**
>
> Before you can use multiple accounts, you need to log into any and all
>   additional accounts you want available.
>
> Launch Settings from your Home screen. Click on Accounts. Click on
>   iTunes and App Store. Click on Add new Apple ID. Enter the additional
>   Apple ID username. Click on Continue. Enter the additional Apple ID
>   password. Click on Sign In.
>
> **How to switch between multiple accounts on Apple TV**
>
> While you have multiple accounts you can only use one account at a
>   time. That means switching!
>
> Launch Settings from your Home screen. Click on Accounts. Click on
>   iTunes and App Store. Click on the account you want to use.
>
> You'll now be able to download or re-download any apps or content
>   available on that account.
>
> **Family Sharing**
>
> Multiple accounts work with Family Sharing, so kids can switch to
>   their accounts and "ask to buy" just like on iPhone or iPad.